# About the logic symbol $\exists$

Tags: soft-question, notation

I know that the symbol $\exists$ means *there exists at least one*

and that the symbol $\exists !$ means *there exists unique*

> So if I want to say that the \$lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ exists,

I can't write $\exists \lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ because this means there exists at least one limit

and I also can't write $\exists ! \lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ because it just doesn't seem right.

I know that both of these statements are correct. Though, is there another symbol for expressing this? Say, $\exists^t$ or something similar?

Comment: Try not to use math symbols as substitutes for language. Don't use "there exists" like this. Just write, "$\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ exists." The symbols exist for shorthand in certain circumstance (e.g., on a blackboard, when you are also speaking an equivalent.) It is also used in highly formal notation.

Comment: you could say $\exists L, \lim_{x \to a} f(x)=L$

Comment: Also, $\exists!$ and $\exists$ are not mutually exclusive. $\exists!$ implies $\exists$.

Comment: you're mixing logic with analysis.

Comment: @Pieter21 So? That's a fun thing to do!

Comment: .. so I'd separate the 'languages' a bit. Mirko's suggestion is excellent in achieving such a thing.

Comment: These pretty valid notations and commonly understood. However just like we seldom write $\implies$, $\land$, $\lor$ in text body, you might want to use it sparely.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly with Mr. Andrews. "$\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ exists" is perfectly clear in a way that "$\exists \lim_{x \to a} f(x)$" and "$\exists ! \lim_{x \to a} f(x)$" are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both statements are right, and since it's easy to prove that at most one limit exists, they are equivalent. So it's ultimately a cosmetic question. In cases like this, almost every text I've seen just uses "$\exists$" to not add an extra symbol.

Something you might like better, though, is the following. **Caution: this is basically never used in this context, I'm just mentioning it because you might find it interesting.** Expressions like "$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)$" are really *partial terms*: they're like "$a+b$," except they're not always guaranteed to exist. In particular, it's *built into their definition* that they be unique. For partial terms, it's often more intuitive to think in terms of a new word, "is defined". E.g. "$a\over b$" is a partial term, and it's a little more helpful to say "$1\over 2$ is defined" than "${1\over 2}$ exists." *I believe there are some texts which say "$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)$ is defined" instead of "exists," but that's rare.* The symbol for this which is used in computability theory, and I believe elsewhere, is "$\downarrow$" for "defined" and "$\uparrow$" for "undefined"; so e.g. one would write $$\mbox{${1\over 2}\downarrow$ but ${1\over 0}\uparrow$}.$$ This way of thinking, I would argue, often matches better what we mean when we say things like "$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)$ exists" better.

**However, it is of course just a cosmetic change, and either "$\exists$" or "$\exists !$" does the job perfectly well; better, I would say, since it doesn't involve introducing a new symbol, and the payoff of "$\downarrow$" and "$\uparrow$" doesn't come until much later.**

Comment: $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) \uparrow$ is kind of irritating :)

Comment: Yes, I knew about this symbol. So, the reason it's not being used in this context is purely because we didn't change it?

Comment: @user251257 That's fair; I personally quite like it, but of course opinions vary.

Comment: @Michael Well, that makes it sound like it objectively should be changed and we just haven't done so. But I'd argue that there is a very good reason for not introducing too many symbols all at once; $\exists$ is a very important one, so with it in hand we don't introduce $\uparrow/\downarrow$ since we judge (correctly or incorrectly) that the costs outweigh the benefits.